# MySQL - Select most recent date out of a set of several possible timestamps?

Tags: mysql, select, timestamp, sql-order-by

I would like to know if this is possible using a mysql query:

I have a table called updates.

In the updates table I have 2 columns, `id` and `timestamp`.

I have 5 rows each with the same `id` but with different date timestamps. An example of this timestamp would be the value: `2012-08-04 23:14:09`.

I would like to select only the most recent timestamp value out of the 5 results. This could also be explained by saying that I would like to select the value that is closest to the current date and time. How could I do this?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
SELECT id, timestamp FROM updates ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 13):

have you tried `SELECT MAX(timestamp)` ?