# MySQL Call Recent Timestamp in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I've seen some similar types of questions on SO, however, I have not been able to find a solution to my specific issue. I want to get recent timestamp and call it in a PHP code. (FYI, these are not my real columns, just a shortened example).

`my_table`

```
row_1         row_2                  TimeStamp
======================================================
 01              04              2014-06-24 22:00:00
 02              01              2014-06-25 19:00:00   
 03              93              2014-06-27 14:00:00
 04              83              2014-06-27 14:31:20 <=== I would like to return this row (latest time)
```

So, what I want to do is be able to:

```
1) Select the "newest" row, based on timestamp AND
2) Select the 'row_2' column accordingly to the timestamp
```

Any help on this would be great.

Thanks in Advanced!

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Select By Newest Timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912221/mysql-select-by-newest-timestamp)

Comment: I'm using Mysql database..

Comment: @MarkM yeah.. I just edited.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL - Select most recent date out of a set of several possible timestamps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11812215/mysql-select-most-recent-date-out-of-a-set-of-several-possible-timestamps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  SELECT `newest`, `user_2` 
    FROM `your_table`
ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC
   LIMIT 1
```

The LIMIT 1 is there in order to only fetch one set of data.

Answer (score 0):

I think this query is what you looking for

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE TimeStamp = (SELECT max(TimeStamp) FROM my_table)
```

Best regards,
Nebojsa